# Question on comparing veggies and alcohol flagged as personal medical question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[What's the difference between diuretic veggies and alcohol that make the latter bad?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/whats-the-difference-between-diuretic-veggies-and-alcohol-that-make-the-latter)

It's only remotely related to health, and even then it's just the context of the question, not the question itself. How do I make it clearer that I'm not asking this for myself or from a health perspective, but rather the comparison of two objective things : veggies and alcohol. (how is one better than the other, in this specific case (diuretic nature))?

Comment: I agree with you. I saw another question that was closed recently for the same reason that I also didn't think deserved it.

Comment: The question looks fine and it has been reopened

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked about is fine. I don't know why it was considered a personal medical question, but as The Last Word says, it has been reopened.

Those of you who vote to close, think before you act. Is the question really off topic? Don't go by what you think should be a standard, go by what is officially the standard. Also, don't just vote to close 'because everyone else did'.